# How to target Apple Java from JDK?

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, java-8

Will targeting Java 6 allow my program to run in Apple Java? Are there any differences between Oracle JRE 6 and Apple Java 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not using classes from "com.sun" package, you will be fine. Apple provides JRE 6, but users can also manually install JRE 7.